# "Short-five-lemma" and "five-lemma"

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Jacobson in Basic Algebra Vol. 2 (p.100) states short five lemma as follows:

> Let $0\rightarrow M'\rightarrow M\rightarrow M''\rightarrow 0$ and $0\rightarrow N'\rightarrow N\rightarrow N''\rightarrow 0$ be short exact sequences of modules, and let $u:M'\rightarrow N'$, $v:M\rightarrow N$ and $w:M''\rightarrow N''$ be morphisms.
> If any two among $u,v,w$ are isomorphisms, then so is the third.

If we see the five-lemma on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_lemma), then the $0$'s are replaced by some modules, and the maps $u,v,w$ are replaced by some morphisms. So, there are totally five morphisms from one chain to another. However, the statement of the lemma looks like,

> *if some morphisms are isomorphisms, some are epimorphisms, some are monomorphisms, then something is isomorphism*.

Is there any way to come from short-five lemma to the five lemma? How one thinks about -  which conditions on four morphisms from one chain to another should be put to conclude about fifth morphism? There could be $3^4$ possible conditions on vertical four morphisms from one chain to another.

Comment: The diagram has many symmetries, for example because the dual of an Abelian category is Abelian. Did you try to use this to reduce the number of cases? If so, what can you say then?

Comment: Sorry, I am not much familiar with duality etc.

Comment: I would guess it is more the other way around, although one might get from short 5 lemma to 5 lemma in  these general cases the water gets really muddy about what implies what, as both hold in  general abelian cats. However, it is very straight forward to see that short five lemma is a special case of the ordinary 5 lemma.
Also, when deriving abelian cats one wants triangles to imitate more the short five lemma as one just has remnants of short exact sequences and not longer ones.